# debug output from an ActiveX control

Tags: debugging, activex, tstcon32

I'm developing an ActiveX control and I'd like to throw some debug output to the console area in tstcon32 like other controls are doing.  What system call is doing that?

stdout doesn't seem to be it

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of ATLTRACE2 ?
"Reports warnings to an output device, such as the debugger window, according to the indicated flags and levels."

Comment: Not sure, I'll give that a try

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's using OutputDebugString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx